# How to add the jbdc driver of Apache IoTDB to dbeaver?

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know why dbeaver version 23.2.3 driver management cannot add jdbc driver of Apache IoTDB? I tried to add `iotdb-jdbc-1.2.2-jar-with-dependencies` and the folder `apache-iotdb-1.2.2-all-bin\lib` but both have failed. There's no driver can be seen under the driver category of dbeaver. I want to know how to successfully add the IoTDB driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use maven method in Apache IoTDB to import the jdbc driver by adding an artifact.